# Canonical and grand canonical formalism at zero temperature

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

How can I find the expectation value of any operator at zero temperature in quantum statistical mechanics formalism? Expectation value of any operator $\hat{O}$ is given as
$$\langle \hat{O}\rangle = Z^{-1}\mathop{\mathrm{Tr}}[\hat{O} e^{-\beta \hat{K}}]$$

where $Z = \mathop{\mathrm{Tr}}[e^{-\beta \hat{K}}]$, $\hat{K} = \hat{H}-\mu\hat{N}$ for grand canonical and $\hat{K}=\hat{H}$ for canonical ensemble. And $\beta=1/T$.

At $T=0\implies \beta=\infty$, which means 
$$e^{-\beta\hat{K}}=0 \Longrightarrow Z=0\quad\text{and}\quad \langle\hat{O}\rangle=0/0=\infty$$

My question not about explaining the procedure for finding the expectation value at $T = 0$. I am only asking how does quantum statistical formalism work at $T = 0$ because for the above given reason, I am confused.

Comment: Have you tried directly taking the limit with some common examples?

Comment: The system is in its ground state at $T = 0$.  Your density operator simply turns into $\rho = | \psi_0 \rangle \langle \psi_0 |$, where $| \psi_0 \rangle$ is the lowest energy quantum state: $\hat{H} | \psi_0 \rangle = E_{\text{min}} | \psi_0 \rangle$.

Comment: @probably_someone  Thank you for suggesting this. I found some examples for canonical ensembles. In limit $\beta \to \infty$, only state with lowest energy survive i.e. $H |\psi_0\rangle = E_{0} |\psi_0\rangle$. What happens in grand canonical case? Does chemical potential have no effect in $T\to 0$ limit?

Comment: @Cham thank you. How does chemical potential effect the ground state in zero temperature limit?

Comment: @LuqmanSaleem, actually, I'm not sure for the chemical potential.  I believe it is 0 when $T \rightarrow 0$.  If not, then the quantum state may be a eigenvector of the operator $\hat{K} = \hat{H} - \mu \hat{N}$.

Comment: @Cham to my understanding, chemical potential is measurement of how much work you have to do to stick a new particle in the system. If it's zero, it means that we don't have to do any work to add a new particle to the system - which does not seem physical to me because particles may interact and repel each other.
Anyhow, let me put the problem in a mathematical way. (in my next comment)

Comment: @Cham we want to solve the following limit:
 $$\lim_{\beta\to\infty} \frac{\sum_i \langle\psi_i| e^{\beta\mu\hat{N}}e^{-\beta\hat{H}}\hat{O}|\psi_i\rangle}{\sum_i \langle\psi_i| e^{\beta\mu\hat{N}}e^{-\beta\hat{H}}|\psi_i\rangle}
= 
\lim_{\beta\to\infty} \frac{\sum_i e^{-\beta E_i} \langle\psi_i| e^{\beta\mu\hat{N}}\hat{O}|\psi_i\rangle}{\sum_i e^{-\beta K_i}\langle\psi_i| e^{\beta\mu\hat{N}}|\psi_i\rangle}$$
with $\hat{H}|\psi_i\rangle=E_i|\psi_i\rangle$ and $E_i<E_{i+1}$. What do you think, doesn't think limit diverges for large beta?

Comment: I agree that the chemical potential may not be 0 at $T \rightarrow 0$.  I guess the quantum state should be the one which minimize $\hat{K} = \hat{H} - \mu \hat{N}$.  Since $\hat{N}$ commute with the hamiltonian, I think the quantum state is still the one which minimize the total energy.  So $\rho = |\phi_0 \rangle \langle \psi_0|$ at $T = 0$.